# Is a triple shvus allowed?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, number, derabanan, shinuy-deviation

Is there a concept of shvus dishvus  with an added shvus making it a rabbinic prohibition 3 times removed. For example if it's yom tov sheini, and the action is rabbinic such as Nolad (turning on a flame on yom tov is prohibited from Nolad), and doing it with a Shinui. Does this make it permissible because it's so far removed?

Comment: In the case you bring as an example - of Yom Tov Sheini - it's not a "triple Shvus" as **Yom Tov Sheini is not a Shvus**. Yom Tov Sheini is - in some ways - more serious than the first day of Yom Tov, with Chazal saying some nasty things about people who don't treat it as a real Yom Tov.

Comment: @Shokhet the qeustion has nothing to do with shinuyim...

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought David was asking a question about doing a `shvus dishvus by way of shinuy`. If he wasn't, feel free to remove the tag. David, what *were* you asking?

Comment: @Shokhet It sounds like he's asking about a "shvus dishvus with an added shvus". Your case is potentially an example of that category.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, @DoubleAA. If you feel the tag doesn't apply, remove it, by all means.